# Async exception handling works when using ensure_future but not when using run_until_complete

Tags: python, logging, python-asyncio

I am using [aiologger](https://github.com/b2wdigital/aiologger) for async logging, and have written two functions to override default exception handlers:

```py
from aiologger import Logger as AioLogger
from aiologger.levels import LogLevel
import asyncio

logger = AioLogger.with_default_handlers(name='test', level=LogLevel.NOTSET,
                                         loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())

def excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print('excepthook called.')
    if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        return
    logger.error(f'Uncaught Exception: {exc_type.__name__}')

def asyncio_exception_handler(loop, context):
    print('asyncio_exception_handler called.')
    exception = context.get('exception', None)
    if exception:
        exc_info = (type(exception), exception, exception.__traceback__)
        if issubclass(exception.__class__, KeyboardInterrupt):
            sys.__excepthook__(*exc_info)
            return
        logger.error(f'Uncaught Exception: {exc_info[0].__name__}')
    else:
        logger.error(context['message'])
```

Then, I overrode the exception handlers with the ones I have provided:

```py
import sys

sys.excepthook = excepthook
asyncio.get_event_loop().set_exception_handler(asyncio_exception_handler)
```

Finally, I wrote a simple code to test the functionality:

```py
async def main():
    raise RuntimeError('Uncaught Test')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

This works as expected, and the output is:

```
asyncio_exception_handler called.
Uncaught Exception: RuntimeError
^Cexcepthook called.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/sample.py", line 110, in <module>
    loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 468, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

(The process remains open after the exception, and I have to send `KeyboardInterrupt` to terminate it.)

---

However, if I replace `asyncio.ensure_future(main())` with `loop.run_until_complete(main())`, everything goes crazy and the application exits without any logs:

```sh
$ python main.py 
excepthook called.
$
```

The confusing part is, in this case, my `excepthook` function is executed instead of `asyncio_exception_handler`. My perception is that somehow using `loop.run_until_complete()` will treat the code to be non-async, hence calling `logger.error()` which creates an async task, has no effects.

---

How can I manage to use my exception handlers to log uncaught exceptions when my code is running with `loop.run_until_complete()`? What is the difference between the two scenarios I have provided? I am not so good with `asyncio`, and I may have missed some trivial notes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AioLogger` is an async logging framework that depends on the event loop to run. When you raise from `ensure_future`, your event loop is still running until you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, which is why you see the log. On the other hand, when you use `run_until_complete(main())`, nothing will run the event loop after `run_until_complete` raises, so the log message scheduled by `excepthook` will be dropped.

To fix the issue, you can run something like `asyncio.sleep(0.001)` after the logger calls in `excepthook` to ensure that the log messages go through:

```
def excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print('excepthook called.')
    if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
        return
    logger.error(f'Uncaught Exception: {exc_type.__name__}')
    # sleep a bit to give the log a chance to flush
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0.001))
```

In general, the asyncio exception handler is meant as a last-resort error reporting, not something you should rely on for your business logic. When you call `run_until_complete()`, there is no reason to pass the exception to the asyncio exception handler because the exception is propagated to the caller of `run_until_complete()`, which can just handle it in the usual way. (In your case `sys.excepthook` is called because the error propagates to top-level.) When you call `ensure_future`, you get a `Future` instance (or instance of its `Task` subclass) that you can either `await` or call `result()` or `exception()` to get the exception. If you do none of that and just allow the future to get destroyed by GC, it will pass the exception to the asyncio handler to log it.

Comment: I'm only returning on `KeyboardInterrupt` instances. The raised exception is `RuntimeError` and is not returned. You can safely ignore that part. This is really my last-resort error handling solution, since intentionally, I have non-awaited coroutines, and also there are exceptions which happen in asyncio world and is not returned to the userspace (I can name [this issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3535) and its solution as an example), and I want to log these tracebacks in JSON and send it to my log aggregation system.

Comment: Also, there are always some uncaught exceptions, indicating unhandled paths by developers. I want my logging platform to successfully log and ship them in my structured format. As you know, Docker and other container runtimes aren't so good at handling multi-line logs (each line will be treated as a separate log). This is why I need a solution for uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @AliTou Correct, the issue is something completely different. I've now amended the answer to address it.

Comment: I got your point. Thank you for your comments. I figured out that when something unhandled in `run_until_complete()` fails, the loop itself will fail, and event running `asyncio.sleep()` doesn't help. The only way to come over it was really catch the exception (since, as you said, it is propagated to the top level). Since I am not losing my loop in my processes, I am fine with the way I am currently logging my uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @AliTou I find it interesting that `asyncio.sleep()` doesn't help. Just to eliminate confusion, I was referring to modifying the top-level code [like this](https://pastebin.com/rHRagW02), and it now occurs to me that it might be even better to just modify the `excepthook` [like this](https://pastebin.com/E2nYqV8z).

Comment: Yay! The second one is really good. I have access to the `loop` object using `logger.loop` and the exception is logged successfully now. It may be good to include it in your answer too. Thanks!

Comment: @AliTou I've now included it in the answer. You might want to try changing `asyncio.sleep(0.001)` to `logger.shutdown()` (as in the example [here](https://aiologger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html)) to actually ensure that pending logs are flushed.